# HTML shows Flask-SQLAlchemy syntax?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

When trying to display replies of users on my page it displays them with SQL syntax, like so: ('reply',) I've tried `str()` when returning from my route.
html:

```
<ul style="float:left;" class="list-group list-group-flush" id="anons">
{% for reply in replies %}
    <li class="list-group-item" align="left">
        {{ reply }}
    </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

model:

```
class Reply(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
```

route:

```
@views.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        data = request.form.get("reply")

        if len(data) >= 1:
            new_reply = Reply(name=name, data=data)
            db.session.add(new_reply)
            db.session.commit()
            replies = db.session.query(Reply.data)

            return render_template('home.html', replies=replies)

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `replies` definition to this:

```py
replies = Reply.query.all()
```

This essentially creates a list of all the 'Reply' objects, which you then pass to the template. If you were wanting to only show the `.data` attribute of each 'Reply', you would access that with `{{ reply.data }}` in the for loop.